How to get the date range dimension field in custom Looker Studio connector
I am developing a custom Looker Studio Connector that are getting data from the backend.
Connector is getting dateRange (start and end date) but did not get the field this filter must be applied to.
Is it any way how to get the Date Range Dimension field selected for the chart to apply filtering on connector's side to chosen field ?
I did not find anything about this in the official documentation also digging into the request and other available variables in the App Scripts did not give any result.
